# lines with color appearing on screen when using tool

Tags: transforms, tools, lines, screencast

i have a problem,everytime i try to use the rotation tool or the tool to move random lines appear on me screen, the things i tried and didnt worked are:
-Reinstall blender
-Delete the folder Blender Fundation on %appdata%

i would be happy to find a solution for this problem,thanks.[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like a graphics problem. Have you checked that you have the latest graphics drivers installed on your machine?

Comment: @JohnEason nope,i didnt checked them